# Insert a Newline Character using Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to insert a newline character using a regex replace like so:

```
strFile = Regex.Replace(
    strFile,
    @"(FA|BO)\s+(\d{3}-\d+)(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)(\d+,*\d*\.\d+)\s*(FA|BO)\s+(\d{3}-\d+)(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)(\d+,*\d*\.\d+)\s*",
    @"$2&$4&$6\n$8&$10&$12"
)
```

but I end up with (literally) `word\nword` rather than an actual newline.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove `@`?

Comment: how , really not Understand
if I remove arroba then I can use newline \n

Comment: when i replace this not get newlinw only get literal  \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `@""` string literal for the replacement string, you're disabling the escape character parsing.  If you make the change to the second string to be a normal string, since you don't have any `\` characters you need to maintain, it'll work as you're expecting.

```
strFile = Regex.Replace(
    strFile, 
    @"(FA|BO)\s+(\d{3}-\d+)(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)(\d+,*\d*\.\d+)\s*(FA|BO)\s+(\d{3}-\d+)(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)(\d+,*\d*\.\d+)\s*",
    "$2&$4&$6\n$8&$10&$12");
```

Comment: i understand now but i omissed the character \r

Comment: @jhonny625 - See "Verbatim string literals" in the [MSDN C# string Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)