# Line Break after Each alphabet in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in (horizontal) form `184.b189.a194.b199.d204.d209.b214.b219.d` which i need to convert in (vertical) form

```
184.b
189.a
194.b
199.d
.......
```

I have tried `Regex` to find each alphabet using below *regex expression* so I could append line break `<br />` after each alphabet in string. Expression works fine, I could not figure out how to *append* line break

```
 var count = Regex.Matches(text, @"[a-zA-Z]");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just split at every 5 characters?

Comment: I think you should generate a string which divides values by , or | or ;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a Newline Character using Regex Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407323/insert-a-newline-character-using-regex-replace)

Comment: By '[alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet)' do you mean 'character' ??

Comment: @TaW OP is probably from India, see https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/alphabet#Noun, meaning 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_): we *replace* each `A..Za..z` match with itself `$0` followed by a new line

```
  string source = "184.b189.a194.b199.d204.d209.b214.b219.d";

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, "[A-Za-z]", $"$0{Environment.NewLine}");

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
184.b
189.a
194.b
199.d
204.d
209.b
214.b
219.d
```

Same idea if you want to add `<br />`

```
  string result = Regex.Replace(source, "[A-Za-z]", $"$0<br />");
```

*Linq* is an alternative:

```
  string result = string.Concat(source
    .Select(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' 
                   ? c.ToString() + "<br />" 
                   : c.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `(\d{3}\.[A-Za-z])` https://regex101.com/r/Z05cC4/1,

which is:

```
\d{3} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{3} Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [A-Za-z]
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
```

Then take the first group only.

---

```
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"184.b189.a194.b199.d204.d209.b214.b219.d";
        IEnumerable<string> capturedGroups = ExtractNumbers(input);

        string res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, capturedGroups);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> ExtractNumbers(string Input)
    {
        string pattern = @"(\d{3}\.[A-Za-z])";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(Input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
            yield return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

Outputting:

```
184.b
189.a
194.b
199.d
204.d
209.b
214.b
219.d
```